# :id Route overwrites others

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: UserComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent }
    ]},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: '0', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: '0', component: NoListComponent },
          { path: ':id', component: ListComponent },
        ]},
      { path: 'createlist', component: CreateListComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: CreateTaskComponent }
    ]},
];
```

Somehow when I call `routerLink="dashboard/create"` or `routerLink="dashboard/createlist"`, the ListComponent (:id) is being displayed with no content, but not CreateListComponent or CreateTaskComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answers are right, I just wanted to clarify one thing. When it comes to route the order matters. So you need to put `/createlist` and `/create` before `:id`

```
{
  path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent, children: [
    {
      path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '0', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'createlist', component: CreateListComponent },
        { path: 'create', component: CreateTaskComponent },
        { path: '0', component: NoListComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: ListComponent }
      ]
    },

  ]
},
```

If you put them after `:id` it will override them because, `:id` will match any nested route that comes after `/dashboard`

Answer (score 1):

You need change your routing configuration as shown below:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [{
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [{
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '0',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: '0',
                component: NoListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'createlist',
                component: CreateListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: CreateTaskComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: ListComponent
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

this is required because `/createlist` and `/create` are both children of `/dashboard`. Do note the order of the paths listed above as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are a little bit confusing for angular. When you call `/dashboard/create`, angular thinks you are trying to reach `/dashboard/:id` with the id value set to "create". Your paths should be unique and not prone to ambiguity.

i would declare it like this

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'no-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'no-list', component: NoListComponent },
          { path: 'list/show/:id', component: ListComponent },
          { path: 'list/createlist', component: CreateListComponent },
          { path: 'list/createtask', component: CreateTaskComponent },
]}
```